# Сохранение измений во всех дочерних RichTextBox'ах

Tags: visual-studio, c#

Здравствуйте)

Каким образом, при закрытие программы, проверить были ли совершены изменения в RichTextBox'ах?

К примеру, сейчас они создаются таким образом:

```
private void project(string name)
{
        tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();//очистка вкладок
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(name);
        foreach (FileInfo files in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(files.Name);
            RichTextBox textBox = new RichTextBox();
            textBox.Parent = tabControl1.TabPages[numTbPg];
            textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            OpenFile(textBox, name + "/" + files.Name);
            textBox.Show();
            textBox.Name = "RichTextBox" + Convert.ToString(numTbPg + 1);
            numTbPg++;
        }
}
```

Понятно что должна существовать переменная, которая меняет свое значение при событие OnChange в RichTextBox, к примеру, переменная Save типа Boolean.

Я думаю, что можно создать класс, в котором будет создаваться объект RichTextBox и определяться его свойства, к примеру:

```
public class MyRichTextBox
{
       RichTextBox textBox = new RichTextBox();
       Form1 frm1 = this.Owner as Form1;
       textBox.Parent = frm1.tabControl1.TabPages[frm1.numTbPg];
       textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       textBox.Show();
       textBox.Name = "RichTextBox" + Convert.ToString(frm1.numTbPg + 1);
       frm1.numTbPg++;
       bool Save = true;
}
```

Как мне теперь обработать событие OnChange?

Про сохранение, я также думаю, что можно в главной форме, просмотреть все вкладки TabControl, получить дочерний элемент, т.е. экземпляр класса MyRichTextBox, и проверить его переменную Save, и обработать потом. Сделать я думаю можно так:

```
foreach (TabPage page in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
     ....
}
```

Как мне теперь получить дочерний элемент?..

Помогите решить проблему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается второго вопроса, для того что бы получить дочерний элемент нужно использовать метод page.FindControl("YourNameControl"). По первому (как обработать onChange), если я правильно понял, то сравнить, то что было изначально, с тем что стало после onChange. Если не равно, то Save=false. (Кстати, позволю себе заметить, что лучше свойство Save переименовать в IsSave, а то звучит как метод, а еще лучше, на мой взгляд, не IsSave, а IsChange - был изменен или не был, тогда изначально IsChange=false, но это уже совсем другая история:) )

**UPD** (не знаю, как код писать в комментариях)

Для начала необходимо создать метод, который будет вызываться при изменении текста с такой вот сигнатурой.

```
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{    
    //Твой код
}
```

А далее в том месте, где создаются контролы повесить обработчик события

```
 textbox.TextChanged+=textChangedEventHandler;
```

Можно один на всех, тогда будет так:

```
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{    
     //определяем, кто генерировал событие
     MyRichTextBox textboxt = (MyRichTextBox) sender;
     //содержимое изменилось
     textbox.Save=false;
    //Твой код 
}
```

**UPD2**
Если тебе нужно проверить был ли изменен текст, то свой класс создавать не нужно.

```
 private void project(string name)
    {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();//очистка вкладок
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(name);
            foreach (FileInfo files in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(files.Name);
                RichTextBox textBox = new RichTextBox();

                //Вешаем обработчик события на контрол
                textBox.TextChanged+=TextChange;

                textBox.Parent = tabControl1.TabPages[numTbPg];
                textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                OpenFile(textBox, name + "/" + files.Name);
                textBox.Show();
                textBox.Name = "RichTextBox" + Convert.ToString(numTbPg + 1);
                numTbPg++;
            }
    }
```

И сам обработчик события

```
private void TextChange(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{    
     //а вот здесь творчество
     RichtTextBox mytextbox = (RichtTextBox)sender;
     MessageBox.Show(@"Текст был изменен в " + mytextbox.Name);

}
```

Также можно создать статическую переменную или List, например

```
static bool IsChange = false;
static List<string> changestextbox =new List<string>();
private void TextChange(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{    
     //тогда так
     //текст где-то изменился
     IsChange=true;

     //запишем в список имя RichtTextBox-а, текст которого изменился
     RichtTextBox mytextbox = (RichtTextBox)sender;
     changestextbox.Add(mytextbox.Name);
}
```

Comment: как мне обработать, создать событие onChange?.. и как получить переменную save?..

Comment: смотри upd

Comment: ммм интересно... получается метод создавать в классе?! а как их инициализировать, к примеру если при создание вкладки инициализировать объект, то он будет  затираться как я думаю... или я ошибаюсь?.. как поступить? или можно использовать массив объектов, к примеру, а потом в каждом проверять на изменение?...

Comment: IsChange получается общая для всех экземпляров RichTextBox? т.е если один раз изенили то она для всех будет.. А вот про лист эт интересно, получается если изменился, то заносим в List имя RichTextBox... Потом при закрытие смотрим весь List и сохраняем изменения во всех RichTextBox...

Comment: Да кстати там не
 
    ( ,TextChangeEventArgs args)

а
 
    ( ,EventArgs e)

А чтобы код был в комментариях, нужно изначально 4 пробела сделать)

    //код

Answer (score 0):

FindControl нет метода, но дочерний элемент можно получить к примеру так:

```
            string selectPage="";
            foreach (Control inTab in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
            {
                if (inTab.GetType() == typeof(RichTextBox))
                {
                    selectPage = inTab.Name;
                }
            }            
            MessageBox.Show(selectPage);
```

А именно, я нашел свой RichTextBox так:

```
            RichTextBox txtBox = new RichTextBox();
            foreach (Control inTab in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
            {
                txtBox = (RichTextBox)inTab;
            }
            txtBox.Text = "Вот Он";
```

Работает)

Comment: FindControl - метод в asp.net, я думал, что и в WindowsForm тоже он будет. В windows form по-другому http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=VS.90).aspx. А вот ссылка http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms742880(v=vs.90).aspx там определение момента изменения текста для TextBox, для RichTextBox также будет. Если использовать TextChangeEventArgs, то можно узнать, что изменилось вот ссылка http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs_members(v=VS.90).aspx